# Is there a way to make expect() output a more user-friendly message?

Tags: rust

I find the message produced by [`expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) to be very unfriendly for users. Consider the following short example...

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let imagefn = env::args().skip(1).next().expect("Filename not provided.");
    println!("{}", imagefn);
}
```

That errors with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Filename not provided.', libcore/option.rs:960:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I find `expect()` very useful for writing quick code, but wish I could output something more like this:

```
Filename not provided.
```

With all the other information hidden unless I actually provide the environment variable, which I, as a developer, should know about. I guess my questions are:

1. Is there a way I can override `expect()` to do this?
2. Why does `expect()` output its unfriendly message even in release builds?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam* — I've removed that from your otherwise good question.

Comment: Overall, I think you are looking at this incorrectly. `expect` should **never** be used for errors that a user might reasonably see or cause. It's intention is for programmer-level errors. Everything else should be handled by your program.

Comment: @Shepmaster I get that. I wrote "I find expect() very useful for writing quick code" ... you're right that real error handling should be used in non-trivial scripts.

Comment: `expect` can be improved with a macro, https://crates.io/crates/unwrap for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) to change the panic message. Example:

```
use std::panic::set_hook;

fn main() {
    set_hook(Box::new(|info| {
        if let Some(s) = info.payload().downcast_ref::<String>() {
            println!("{}", s);
        }
    }));

    // Displays: "My error message":
    Option::None::<i32>.expect("My error message");
}
```

You can also use `message()` that is simpler, but [unstable (for now)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66745):

```
#![feature(panic_info_message)]

use std::panic::set_hook;

fn main() {
    set_hook(Box::new(|info| {
        println!("{:?}", info.message().unwrap());
    }));

    Option::None::<i32>.expect("My error message");
}
```

Note that you can create your own extension method that panics with a custom type. In the panic hook, if you can downcast to your custom type, you are certain of the origin of the panic.

Answer (score 7):

[`expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#309-314) is just a convenient conditional call to `panic!()`:

```
pub fn expect(self, msg: &str) -> T {
    match self {
        Some(val) => val,
        None => expect_failed(msg) // expect_failed calls panic!()
    }
}
```

Ideally you should probably handle this with the `?` operator inside a function returning an `Option` or `Result` in order to be able to handle this sort of issue in a more graceful manner.

If you would just like to return a more friendly-looking message and quit, you could implement your own function printing the message and terminating with [process::exit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/fn.exit.html).