# Include the friendly error string in expect

Tags: rust

Is it possible to include the error string in errors output by `expect`? I want to write some quick validation errors, but I'm trying to avoid writing boilerplate.

Using `match` error handling gets a clear error string:

```
let url = match Url::parse("sdfsf") {
    Ok(url) => url,
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("Error parsing URL: {}", e);
        return;
    }
};
// Output:
// Error parsing URL: relative URL without a base
```

However, `expect` prints the error type:

```
let url = Url::parse("sdfsf").expect("Error parsing URL");
// Output:
// thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:41:35:
// Error parsing URL: RelativeUrlWithoutBase
```

And I can't see any way to access that error from `set_hook` if [I tried to override error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786498/is-there-a-way-to-make-expect-output-a-more-user-friendly-message).

It seems that `unwrap_or_else` is the tersest way to express this error with the nice message:

```
let url = Url::parse("sdfsf").unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    panic!("Error parsing URL: {}", e);
});
// Output:
// thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:33:9:
// Error parsing URL: relative URL without a base
```

Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect()` does print the error, but as [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) and not user-facing [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html). You cannot change that. But you can make your own method that prints using `Display`:

```rust
pub trait ExpectExt<T> {
    fn expect(self, msg: &str) -> T;
}

impl<T, E: std::fmt::Display> ExpectExt<T> for Result<T, E> {
    fn expect(self, msg: &str) -> T {
        self.unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("{msg}: {err}"))
    }
}
```

However, `expect()` panics on failure, and panic messages are not meant for users. If an application panics this is a bug, so panic messages are meant for the developers. Therefore, `Debug` is appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It made me think more about debug vs user errors in rust and helped me come up with a more [appropriate question (and solution!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78217448/simple-error-handling-for-precondition-argument-checking-in-rust/78217464) for terse error handling.